# Insert a random variable into WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, testing

I want to insert a random variable into a WordPress post. To be more specific, the user who completes the test gets their score, i.e "You've got 10 out of 10" and I want to insert a text saying "Your score is better than 90% of the users who completed the test". But each time I want the percentage to be different in the range that I choose, for example, 85-100%. So each time someone completes the test, the text would display a variable with a percentage from 85% to 100%. Is this possible?

I'm using a WordPress plugin that is not updated anymore and I'd like to add some extra functions to it. At this point, it only lets me insert a text depending on how many correct answers the user had.

```
$percents = (int) round((($correctanswers/$attemptstoanswers) * 100), 0);
if ($percents > 0 && $percnets <= 33)
else if ($percents > 33 && $percents <= 67)
else if ($percents > 67 && $percents <= 100)
```

I have of course searched before posting this question. But the only result I found was inserting a defined variable via functions.php and shortcode. I don't want a defined variable, I want it to be random from a specified range.

```
add_shortcode('varnumber', 'my_var_number');
function my_var_number($atts, $content = null) {
    return 'Put whatever number you want here instead of this text';
}
```

I'd like the code to return a random percentage varying from a selected range.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ - Yes. You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65155864/edit) to add all relevant code. You also need to tell us exactly where you're stuck and what currently happens. We are here to help you fix issues with your code, which requires you to show it l and explain the issue properly. That's a minimum when asking.

Comment: [Random](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand) is pretty easy to achieve. Side notes: 1) Making your range 85-100% doesn't make sense, because it would mean the user did better than themselves :) 85-99% would be more sensible. 2) There's a typo in the code: `&& $percnets <= 33`, it says "percnets" instead of "percents".